# How to make macOS archive RAR and unRAR files in Finder with automator and shell script?

Tags: macos, terminal, automator, rar

I have rar and unrar installed in `/usr/local/bin/`. I need:

1. In Finder: to archive selected files and folders with .rar extension to the same folder. Is it possible to make it through right click and context menu? Or with automator services?
2. In Finder: Unrar selected archives to the same folder in Finder with context menu.

Is it possible with automator and shell script?

Comment: RE: "Is it possible with automator and shell script?", **yes** it's doable.

Comment: @user3439894, how can I do this?

Comment: @user3439894, I have macOS Catalina. I’m trying to make 2 scenarios:
1. For archiving: There are multiple files and folders all in one folder. When one selects several files and folders, then right click (or goes to Finder>services) and choose «Archive», it archives all selected files and folders into the same folder and creates file archive.rar (or archive«date»«time».rar)

Comment: @user3439894, 2. For unarchiving: There are archive file in a folder. When one selects it with right click (or with Finder>services), and choose «Unarchive», it creates a folder named exactly as archive, in a folder where archive is, and unarchives it into this created folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *example* **shell script** *code* used in this answer was tested under **macOS Catalina 10.15.4**.

As *coded* the *location* the **RAR** *archive* is to be *created/extracted* to must be *readable/writable* to you with normal privileges, otherwise the **RAR** *archive* is *created/extracted* on your **Desktop**. If a selected *file/folder* to be *archived* is not *readable* it will throw an error message and an incomplete **RAR** *archive* may be created.

The two **Automator** *Quick Actions* work as advertised with the *settings* as shown in the images of the *workflows*, further below, so use the same *settings*!

- **Workflow receives current [files or folders] in [Finder]**
- **Run Shell Script** *action*:

  - **Shell: [/bin/bash]**     **Pass input: [as arguments]**

- **NOTE:** In order for these *workflows* to work, **Finder** must be given **Full Disk Access** in: **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy**
- **NOTE:** If `rar` and `unrar` are not properly signed it will throw an error message. Go to **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **General**, click the lock to make changes, enter your credentials, click the **Allow** *button*. You will still have to grant the permission the next time they run, but not there after.

---

## Create RAR Archive

Using how by default in **Finder** a **ZIP** *archive* is created in **macOS**, only recursing the *relative path* from within the **PWD**, the same applies to the *example* **shell script** *code* used in the first **Run Shell Script** *action* of the **Automator** *Quick Action* shown below.

In this first **Automator** *Quick Action*, as *coded*, the *example* **shell script** *code* will:

- Define **RAR** *variables*.
- *Change directory* to the *location* of the *selected file(s)/folder(s)* within the *same parent folder* of the *selected file(s)/folder(s)*.
- Build an *array* of just the *basenames* of the *selected file(s)/folder(s)*.
- Verify the **PWD** is *writable* and if *true*, *create* the **RAR** *archive* in the **PWD**, else *create* it on your **Desktop**.
- Create a **RAR** *archive*, named e.g.:

  - **Archive 2020-04-25 at 10.56.00 PM.rar**
     Containing the *selected file(s)/folder(s)*.

---

```bash
rar_exe="/usr/local/bin/rar"
rar_args="a -r -idq"
rar_archive="Archive $(date '+%Y-%m-%d at %I.%M.%S %p').rar"

cd "$(dirname "$1")" || exit

declare -a my_files
for f in "$@"; do
    my_files+=( "$(basename "$f")" )
done

if [ -w "${PWD}" ]; then
    $("${rar_exe}" ${rar_args} "${rar_archive}" "${my_files[@]}")
else
    $("${rar_exe}" ${rar_args} "${HOME}/Desktop/${rar_archive}" "${my_files[@]}")
fi
```

---

[image: Automator Create RAR Archive Quick Action Image]

---

## Extract RAR Archive

Unlike how by default in **Finder** a **ZIP** *archive* is *extracted* in **macOS**, incrementing the *name* of the *folder* the *archive* is *extracted* to if it previously exists, the *example* **shell script** *code* used in this second **Run Shell Script** *action* of the **Automator** *Quick Action* shown below **does not do that!** If the *folder* named for the *extracted* **RAR** *archive* already exists, then it is not *extracted* a second time.

In you need to *extract* it again, rename or delete the existing *extracted* **RAR** *archive*, or copy the **RAR** *archive* to an alternate *location*, then *extract* it.

In this second **Automator** *Quick Action*, as *coded*, the *example* **shell script** *code* will:

- Define **UNRAR** *variables*.
- *Change directory* to the *location* of the *selected* **RAR** *archive(s)*.
- Verify the *file extension* of the *selected file(s)* is **rar**.
- Verify the **PWD** is writable and if true, *extract* the **RAR** *archive* in the **PWD**, else *extract* it on your **Desktop**.
- Verify a *folder* of the same *name* does not already exist, and if not, then *extract* the contents of the *selected* **RAR** *archive(s)* in a *folder* the *name* of the *selected* **RAR** *archive(s)*.

---

```bash
unrar_exe="/usr/local/bin/unrar"
unrar_args="x -ad -idq"

cd "$(dirname "$1")" || exit

for f in "$@"; do
    [ "${f##*.}" == "rar" ] || continue
    d="${f##*/}"
    if [ -w "${PWD}" ]; then
        [ ! -d "${d%.*}" ] || continue
        $("${unrar_exe}" ${unrar_args} "$f")
    else
        cd "${HOME}/Desktop" || exit
        [ ! -d "${d%.*}" ] || continue
        $("${unrar_exe}" ${unrar_args} "$f")
    fi
done
```

---

[image: Automator Extract RAR Archive Quick Action Image]

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **shell script** *code* is just that and, sans existing *error handling*, does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted.</sub>